# Apache camel Spring Profiles

Tags: spring, apache-camel

HI Is there any example for blog post for apache camel using spring profiles for different DB properties.

I'm trying like below

```
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd           http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
<camelContext id="Demo" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

<Db properties >


<beans:beans profile="dev">
        <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="properties"  ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
        <util:properties id="properties" location="classpath:dev.properties"/>
         <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.environment" />


</beans:beans>


<beans:beans profile="test">
        <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="properties"  ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
        <util:properties id="properties" location="classpath:test.properties"/>
         <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.environment" />


  </beans:beans>

</beans:beans>
```

Its giving Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'bean'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.
Can any one help here, I'm using camel 2.17.3 version

Comment: You’re not closing the `camelContext` tag.